Synthetic geometry problem: Asserting half circles (or half disks)
I would like to solve for $x$ in this plane geometry problem using GeometricScene

Unfortunately, I don't know how to create/assert a half circle (or half disk) and some of the constraints.
Here's a start:
scene = GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, d, 
     o}, {x}}, {CircleThrough[{a, b, c}, o], o == Midpoint[{a, c}],
    EuclideanDistance[a, c] == x}];
RandomInstance[scene, RandomSeeding -> 12345]


There is no need to represent half-circles. You can perfectly well use only Circle.
Here is a very clumsy way of specifying your scene. It can surely be represented in a much more concise way, but it's at least a start for you.
scene = GeometricScene[{{o1, o2, o3, b, c}, {x}}, {
    c1 == Circle[o1, 2/2],
    c2 == Circle[o2, 3/2],
    c3 == Circle[o3, x/2],
    GeometricAssertion[{c1, c2}, "Tangent"],
    GeometricAssertion[{c2, InfiniteLine[{o1, b}]}, {"Tangent", b}],
    GeometricAssertion[{c1, c3}, "PairwiseTangent"],
    GeometricAssertion[{o1, o3, b}, "Collinear"],
    GeometricAssertion[InfiniteLine[{o1, o3}], "Horizontal"],
    GeometricAssertion[{Line[{b, o2}], Line[{o2, c}]}, "Perpendicular"],
    GeometricAssertion[{o3, c}, {"OppositeSides", InfiniteLine[{b, o2}]}],
    c ∈ c2,
    c ∈ c3
    }];
RandomInstance[scene]


GeometricSolveValues[scene, EuclideanDistance[o3, c]]
(* {5/2} *)


Thanks so much ($\checkmark$)!  I do wish there were a way to specify half disks.  After all, we can specify arcs in Graphics as Circle[{0,0},1,{0, Pi}].  Oh... any guess why two downvotes??  Oh wait:  your answer is wrong...  it should be 5... not 5/2.

Ahhh....  5/2 for the radius, 5 for the diameter.... OK.

DiskSegment with RegionDisjoint and RegionWithin, we can get the inequalities, and using CylindricalDecomposition to get the extreme cases.
Clear["Global`*"];
{reg1, reg2, reg3} = {DiskSegment[{1, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], 
   DiskSegment[{u, 3/2}, 3/2, {π, 2 π}], 
   DiskSegment[{x/2, 0}, x/2, {0, π}]};
sol1 = RegionDisjoint[reg1, reg2]
result1 = 
 ToRules@CylindricalDecomposition[sol1 && u > 0, u, "Boundary"]
u = u /. result1;
sol2 = RegionWithin[reg3, RegionUnion[reg1, reg2]]
result2 = ToRules@CylindricalDecomposition[sol2, x, "Boundary"]
x = x /. result2;


u > 3 || u < -1


{u -> 3}


x >= 5


{x -> 5}

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Pink], reg1, FaceForm[Yellow], 
  reg2, Cyan, Opacity[.1], FaceForm[], reg3}]



The above method work for some ellipsoid cases.

Clear["Global`*"];
{reg1, reg2, reg3} = {Disk[{1, 0}, {1, 2/3}, {0, Pi}], 
   Disk[{u, 2}, {1, 2}, {π, 2 π}], 
   Disk[{x/2, 0}, {x/2, 3/5 x}, {0, π}]};
sol1 = RegionDisjoint[reg1, reg2];
result1 = 
  ToRules@CylindricalDecomposition[sol1 && u > 0, u, "Boundary"];
u = u /. result1;
sol2 = RegionWithin[reg3, RegionUnion[reg1, reg2]];
result2 = ToRules@CylindricalDecomposition[sol2, x, "Boundary"];
x = x /. result2;
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Pink], reg1, FaceForm[Yellow], 
  reg2, Cyan, Opacity[.1], FaceForm[], reg3}]



test the 3D cases.

Clear["Global`*"];
{reg1, reg2, reg3} = {Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 2}, {3, 5, 2}], 
   Ellipsoid[{0, u, 4}, {1, 2, 4}], Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 20}}, x]};
sol1 = RegionDisjoint[reg1, reg2];
result1 = 
  ToRules@CylindricalDecomposition[sol1 && u > 0, u, "Boundary"];
u = u /. result1;
sol2 = RegionWithin[reg3, RegionUnion[reg1, reg2]];
result2 = 
  ToRules@CylindricalDecomposition[{sol2, x > 0}, x, "Boundary"];
x = x /. result2;
Graphics3D[{Pink, reg1, Yellow, reg2, White, Opacity[.2], reg3}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> Right,
  PlotRange -> All]



this is is very instructive. Thank you for the education! +1 :)

appreciate the updates testing extension of method

@ubpdqn Thanks!

One way to do this with GeometricScene/RandomInstance/GeometricSolveValues:
With
scene = GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {r, x}}, {
Disk[a, 1, {0, Pi}],
Disk[b, 1.5, {Pi, 2 Pi}],
Disk[d, r, {0, Pi}],
Line[{a, c, b}],
EuclideanDistance[a, c] == EuclideanDistance[a, e] == 1,
EuclideanDistance[b, c] == EuclideanDistance[b, f] == 1.5,
EuclideanDistance[d, e] == EuclideanDistance[d, f] == r,
Indexed[e, 1] < Indexed[a, 1] < Indexed[b, 1] < Indexed[f, 1],
Indexed[a, 2] == Indexed[d, 2] == Indexed[e, 2] == 
Indexed[b, 2] - 1.5 == Indexed[f, 2] - 1.5,
x == 2 r
}]

we have RandomInstance[scene] return

and GeometricSolveValues[scene, x] return {5}.

very nice, esp Line[{a,c,b}]. +1 :)

I have voted for @Domen answer. I post this as it is "fast" relative to GeometricScene (but not as stylistic pleasing or able to deal with complex scenes as GeometricScene and GeometricSolve):
c1 = {1, 0};
c2 = {a, 1.5};
c3 = {b, 0};
sol = Quiet@
   Solve[{{-Sin[t], Cos[t]} == {Sin[s], -Cos[s]}, 
      c1 + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} == c2 + 1.5 {Cos[s], Sin[s]}}, {t, s, 
      a}][[2]];
p1 = c1 + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} /. sol;
p2 = {a, 0} /. sol;
p3 = c2 + 1.5 {1, 0} /. sol;
big = Quiet@
   Solve[{c3 + r {-1, 0} == {0, 0}, (c3 - p3) . (c3 - p3) == r^2}, {b,
       r}][[1]];
Graphics[{Pink, EdgeForm[Red], Disk[c1, 1, {0, Pi}], Yellow, 
  Disk[c2 /. sol, 1.5, {Pi, 2 Pi}], Black, 
  Circle[c3 /. big, r /. big, {0, Pi}], Purple, PointSize[0.01], 
  Point[{c1, c2 /. sol, c3 /. big, p1, p3}], Black, 
  Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}}], 
  Text[Row[{"Diameter: ", 2 r /. big}], c3 /. big, {0, -2}], 
  Text[c1, c1, {-1, -1}], Text[p1, p1, {-1, -1}], 
  Text[c2 /. sol, c2 /. sol, {-1, -1}], Text[p3, p3, {-1, -1}]}, 
 Frame -> True]



I teach a course at Stanford, Computational symbolic mathematics, which is all about computer algebra, and for the chapter/section on geometry I want to use only GeometricScene.  Hence my request for such a solution.  I want my students to get ever more comfortable and proficient in symbolic geometry.

@DavidG.Stork I appreciate that. I think my motivation in posting was other users who might want to use MMA in other ways for such problems.  I respect your desire for teaching use of high level functions in symbolic geometry and that my answer, therefore, misses your point. As I stated I voted for Domen excellent answer: though in my machine it took some time.
